# How to hide tab bar swift ui ios

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui-navigationview, swiftui-tabview

I implemented my own tab bar:

```
struct MainView: View
{
    @State var selectedIndex = 0
    let icons = ["menucard", "house"]
    let iconsNames = ["meniu", "oferte"]


var body: some View{
    
    VStack(spacing: 0){

        ZStack{
            switch selectedIndex{
            case 0:
                MeniuListView()
            case 1:
                ProfileView()
              }

        Divider()
        HStack{
            ForEach(0..<2, id: \.self){number in
                Spacer()
                Button(action: {
                    self.selectedIndex=number

                }, label: {
                    VStack(spacing: 3){
                    Image(systemName: icons[number])
                            .font(.system(size: 25,
                                         weight: .regular,
                                         design: .default))
                           
                 }
              }
          }
}
```

Now the question is how I can hide it if I want to go to a specific view?
What is the best approach to do so?
For example I want to navigate to a `login` page, but the tab bar does not hide..

This is my `ProfileView()` that call the login page but the tab bar does not disappear.. How I can hide it?
ProfileView code:

```
struct ProfileShopView: View {
       @State var goToNextScreen : Int? = nil
        var body: some View {
              NavigationView{
    
                   VStack{
        
                       Form{
                           }
                 
                    NavigationLink(destination: LoginView().navigationBarHidden(true), tag: 1, selection: $goToNextScreen)
                           {    
                              EmptyView()
                           }
                      Button(action: {
                
                           goToNextScreen=1
                           UserDefaults.standard.set(false, forKey: "isLogin")
                
                      } //need to hide the tab bar when navigating to login view
          }
    }
```

Comment: You could use if statements based on a @State variable

Comment: Can you help me with an code example please?

Comment: In your switch code apply toolbar only to the index you want

Comment: Just curious why do you want your own toolbar?

Comment: Is there another better way to do so? any examples?

Comment: If you hide the toolbar how will you navigate to your other view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Approach

- Use a full screen cover for login view
- After sign in login view is dismissed
- Use a tab bar
- Tap on logout show login view again

## Code

### Login

```
struct LoginView: View {
    @Environment(\.dismiss) private var dismiss
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.yellow
            Button("Sign in") {
                dismiss()
            }
            .buttonStyle(.bordered)
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea()
    }
}
```

### Tab

```
enum TabContent: Int {
    case menu
    case profile
}
```

### Content

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var selection = TabContent.menu
    @State private var isLoginShown = true
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            TabView(selection: $selection) {
                Text("Menu list")
                    .tabItem {
                        Label("Menu", systemImage: "list.bullet")
                    }
                    .tag(TabContent.menu)
                
                VStack {
                    Text("Profile view")
                    Button("Logout") {
                        isLoginShown = true
                    }
                }
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Profile", systemImage: "person.crop.circle")
                }
                .tag(TabContent.profile)
            }
        }
        .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isLoginShown) {
            LoginView()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: in my profile view, I have a logout button, when I click the button I want to go to a separate view (nor to menu or profile view) to another different view from the app, a login view, that should not contain the toolbar

Comment: See if the updated code helps

Comment: It is working!!! Thank you!
But when you do **.fullScreenCover**, what happen to the others views?

Comment: `.fullScreenCover` doesn't affect other views, it only is applicable for the login view. `.fullScreenCover` is used so that the login screen fully covers the screen. Normally we would use `.sheet` for modal but that wouldn't cover the entire screen.

Comment: So the other screens wont close? I will still have the data there from the menu, profile views?

Comment: Please watch the WWDC SwiftUI videos to learn the basics of SwiftUI. As much as possible use standard view, but you need to know what is available. Press Command Shift L to see what is already available (Views / Modifiers etc). Learning the basics before building apps will help you in the long run

Comment: Login view just slides up, play around with it and make changes ... I think it is a starting point

Comment: Navigation Stack is only available for ios 16...

Comment: need something for ios 15 too

Comment: use @available and use `NavigationView` for iOS 15

Comment: The problem with this tab bar is that the saving remains between views, for example if I switch from view 1 to 2, when I switch back to view 1, the things changed remain saved, the view does not reset

Comment: The selection is stored in `selection` so set it when ever you like `onAppear` / `onDisappear` or what ever event you want. IMHO it would be best if you learn the fundamentals before jumping into app development. In the long run it will really help you know the basics, start with Apple tutorials ... WWDC has some great content for SwiftUI, start with https://developer.apple.com/wwdc20/10119